# AWS Amplify how to include validation across two model attributes? (e.g. startDate < endDate)

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, aws-amplify, aws-serverless

Using AWS Amplify how does one update the schema.graphql model file so as to cause backend validation across multiple fields for the graphql API that is created.

For example with the following schema.graphql file for amplify, how could I update this (or with the additional of other files in the project), so as to include a server side validation check on the graphql API it created such that:

> "startDate should be before endDate"

schema.graphql file:

```
type Event @model {
  id: ID!
  name: String!
  startDate: AWSDate!
  endDate: AWSDate!
  plan: Plan! @connection(name: "PlanEvents")
}
```

If this is not possible with amplify (note I'm using javascript amplify with react front end), advice re what approach to take to implement would be appreciated (e.g. what backend AWS components would I have to look into and learn, and how this would integrate in with the automated graphql api that amplify is effectively automatically building already for me)

Answer (score 2):

You could add a [custom resolver](https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/cli/graphql#overwrite-a-resolver-generated-by-the-graphql-transform)

Your Event model will cause the creation of a file, `build/Mutation.createEvent.req.vtl`, which can be overwritten by adding a `resolvers/Mutation.createEvent.req.vtl`. In that file you could put the logic to compare the two dates and throw an error. Something like:

```
#if( $ctx.args.input.startDate > $ctx.args.input.endDate )
  $util.error("startDate must be before endDate")
#end
```

Bare in mind I have no idea what the actual syntax for comparing dates in VTL is. [This](http://velocitycoder.com/comparing-dates/) might help